# Validation of .net form

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to use javascript validation and asp.net validators (required field validator) simultaneously on a single button click. Please help me

Comment: ASP.NET validators support clientside validation. Have a look: [ASP.NET Validation in Depth, chapter "Client-Side Validation"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx#aspplusvalid_clientside) You need to set `EnableClientScript` to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET validators support clientside validation.

Have a look: [ASP.NET Validation in Depth, chapter "Client-Side Validation"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx#aspplusvalid_clientside)

You need to set `EnableClientScript` to `true` (but it's the default value anyway).

So the `RequiredFieldValidator` checks  on the client side  if the user entered something.

Comment: I know that it supports client side validation my question is can we use both javascript code validation (some function calling which checks value and allow postback only when it satisfy the condition) and .net custom validaotr if yes then please tell me how?

Comment: Your question is too vague. First you've talked about RequiredFieldValidator and now about CustomValidator. What have you tried, what didn't work?

Comment: You didn't get my question. I want to validate a form and for that i used both  javascript code validation (some function for validation) as well as .net validators (compare or required or any one else) but only .net validators fired is there any way that i can used both this method simultaneously?

Comment: I'm not sure if you've looked at my link. You can use a `CustomValidator` and provide a [ClientValidationFunction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.clientvalidationfunction.aspx).